# PDO Query Not Working

Tags: php, database, html, pdo

I've tested it, the SESSION ID is giving out a valid id, and so is all the other parameters. Help me.

```
$sql = 'UPDATE users SET firstname = :firstname, lastname = :lastname WHERE id = :id'; 
$records->bindParam(':id',$_SESSION['user_id']);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(' ', $nn);

        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);

        if($stmt->execute()) {



        } else {

            die("An error adapted during changes.");

        }
```

Comment: Uhm... you are binding $records, instead of $stmt for the ID. Also, you need to do the bindParam() after the prepare();

Answer (score 0):

I thought your query should be like this.

```
$sql = 'UPDATE users SET firstname = :firstname,      lastname = :lastname WHERE id = :id' ;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(' ', $nn);
$stmt->bindParam(':id',$_SESSION['user_id']); 
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname); 
if($stmt->execute()) {



    } else {

        die("An error adapted during changes.");

    }
```